# Jquery length() not counting on ajax load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to load an external html file which has a bunch of span tags that will count the number of contents in a specific category list at my homepage and the rest of my other pages like "Games(9), Movies(2) etc.." so:

`html` content to load via `ajax` -

```
  <span class="category games">(0)</span>
  <span class-"category movies">(0)</span>
```

main html code to insert the numbers and the loaded ajax content -

```
 <div id="categories">
  <span class="counter cgames">(0)</span>
  <span class="counter cmovies">(0)</span>
 </div>
```

the javascript file -

```
    $( "#categories" ).load( "bunchofspans.html" );
    $(function() {
      var a = $(".movies").length;
            $(".cmovies").text("(" + a + ")");
          a = $(".games").length;
            $(".cgames").text("(" + a + ")");
    });
```

it's easy to add numbers to the counter by simply adding another span with the specific category on a hidden div of `#categories`, so lets say i have 6 number of games on page 1 then on page 2 i have another 6, for a total of 12, which means i need to add 12 span in category games in every pages of my site which is time consuming, so if i load it via `ajax` those spans will have one single place in every pages.

the ajax contents loads perfectly fine, the problem is, the `length()` seems to be not counting no matter how i add more spans, numbers won't fire back at the counter nor increase.

Comment: and you length code , inside the callback funtion of ajax..

Comment: Why is your Javascript commented out?

Comment: Anything that depends on the results of an AJAX call _must_ be done in the AJAX callback function, because AJAX is asynchronous.

Comment: which part mr barmar? sorry im new at stack overflow, my apologies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide a call back to load as below

```
$( "#categories" ).load( "bunchofspans.html",function() {
      var a = $(".movies").length;
            $(".cmovies").text("(" + a + ")");
          a = $(".games").length;
            $(".cgames").text("(" + a + ")");
});
```

Refer http://api.jquery.com/load/ for more.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `javascript` to call the `function()` as a callback to `load()` :

```
$( "#categories" ).load( "bunchofspans.html" , function(){
    var a = $(".movies").length;
    $(".cmovies").text("(" + a + ")");

    a = $(".games").length;
    $(".cgames").text("(" + a + ")");
});
```

[jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the [`Callback Function`](http://api.jquery.com/load/#callback-function) like:

```
$("#categories").load("bunchofspans.html", function () {
    alert("Load was performed.");
    var a = $(".movies").length;
    $(".cmovies").text("(" + a + ")");
    a = $(".games").length;
    $(".cgames").text("(" + a + ")");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your function for counting the number of `span` is executed weather your external html content is loaded or not. And that's because `jQuery.load` is Asynchronous.
From [jQuery.load documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

> It is roughly equivalent to $.get(url, data, success)

So all you need is to move you function to be executed **after** your external html content is fully loaded

```
$( "#categories" ).load( "bunchofspans.html",function() {
      var a = $(".movies").length;
            $(".cmovies").text("(" + a + ")");
          a = $(".games").length;
            $(".cgames").text("(" + a + ")");
});
```